# Django: Proper place to unregister ModelAdmins

Tags: django, django-admin

Sometimes I need to UNREGISTER some ModelAdmins from the admin site, because I don't want them to be there as they are, eg. if I'm using the Sites framework, and I dont want it to appear in the admin. It's no big deal to e.g. call `admin.site.unregister(Site)` to do so. In most cases I put it in `admin.py` of some related app that I have made, but sometimes I end up putting it in a place that hasn't much to do with the original app; another possibility would be making a "dummy app" and put it there...
Does anybody know a more descent place where these calls can live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put it in `urls.py` or wherever you call `admin.autodiscover()`.